# How to make interactive cmd interface?

Tags: c, eof

I was tasked with making an interactive cmd interface in C.
I need to manage a data base of students, and have 3 commands which are : add,remove,print.
I cant get the interactive platform right, I need achieve the following : each time I enter a command, it executes and then waits for new command without exiting, so the linked list won't get deleted of the memory, so far Im stuck here :

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char input[MAX];
    int c;
    if(argc == 1)
    {
        printf("no values were entered");
        exit(0);
    }

    while(--argc>0 )
    {
        ++argv;
        {
            strcpy(input,*argv);
            if((*++argv) )
            {
                printf("\nmain(): too much args\nexit(0)\n");
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    {
        if (strcmp(input,"add") == 0)
            /*do something*/;
        else if(strcmp(input,"print") == 0)
            /*do something*/
        else if(strcmp(input,"remove") == 0)
            /*do something*/
        else
            printf("no command was found\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, this does get my input and do what it is supposed to do, but I cant get my head around on how to make it return and wait for more commands without exiting the program.
Thanks for all information and help in advance!

Comment: Wrap it in a loop where the exit condition could be something like a key press, usually escape. Edit: And what @Someprogrammerdude is saying below. Didn't properly read the code and missed that.

Comment: Command line arguments passed through `argc` and `argv` are the arguments to the actual command. It's not input you read "interactively".

Comment: you need a forever loop like 'while(true)' and in the loop keep checking if there is data and read them 'scanf("%c",&char)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want make an interactive interface you should follow a few steps.

1 - Get the key press by the user like

```
keypress = getch();
```

2 - Switch case the key pressed like

```
switch(keypress)
{
    case 'a' :
       // Do somethink...
    case 'b' :
       // Do somethink
    default :
       break;
}
```

3 - Now put this in while loop like

```
do
{
    keypress = getch();
    switch(keypress)
    {
        case 'a' :
          // Do somethink...
        case 'b' :
          // Do somethink
        default :
          break;
}
while(keypress != 'q')
// quit program...
```

Thanks,
Robin.